# Accessing Facebook Marketing API from Java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

We have Java based CRM and want to integrate facebook campaign management. I checked facebook marketing api and they provide PHP and Python based SDKs. I'm wondering how we can access/consume facebook marketing api in Java, there should be some rest interface which I could not find.

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is newly released Java SDK (beta) for Marketing API: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk. You can give a try.

Comment: Thank You very much. I will be testing it out.

Comment: Jiaming, need little more help. I need guide how to create custom audience and use it in campaign via java sdk? Will be very thankful

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[RestFB](http://restfb.com/)

> The Marketing API support is currently in a beta state and you may use
>   it at your own risk. We would like to hear your feedback and hope you
>   open any issue at Github or write a message to Google Groups.

Here are the Java Docs 
http://restfb.com/javadoc/index.html
http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/ads/AdCampaignGroup.html
http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/ads/class-use/AdCampaignGroup.html

Besides RestFB, Spring Social seems to be the best contender:

- [Java (Spring) by Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social/) - Looks like there is a pull request to integrate the ads management api, but, it hasn't been merged. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/pull/155/files

Additionally, there is also Facebook4j
http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: I did not find any support for ads management in restFB or in graph api? do you know and point to ti ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Marketing API docs are here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

The quickstart is here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/quickstart

The reference is here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v2.5

Even if maybe RestFb does not support this, you can always use direct HTTP calls to the Marketing API (for example via [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/)).

Comment: Well, look at the HttpComponents docs, the only thing you have to fill in is the actual request, which you can abstract from the Marketing API docs.